# how to follow the each request of lambda log

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

Aws lambda makes the log files as log stream

I exported the logs to S3 and downloaded them.

However in that files timestamp dosen't sorted in order.

And sometimes the same request are separated.

Normally

```
2022-08-08T04:08:17.808Z START RequestId: 6ec642a2-84d6-4e09-8155-ad8c0cbefd52 Version: $LATEST

...
...
...

2022-08-08T04:08:18.688Z END RequestId: 6ec642a2-84d6-4e09-8155-ad8c0cbefd52

2022-08-08T04:08:18.688Z REPORT RequestId: 6ec642a2-84d6-4e09-8155-ad8c0cbefd52 Duration: 878.21 ms Billed Duration: 879 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 114 MB
```

Sometimes it is separated.

```
2022-08-08T04:08:17.808Z START RequestId: 6ec642a2-84d6-4e09-8155-ad8c0cbefd52 Version: $LATEST

...
...
...
other RequestID's comes in here.
other logs are listed here
...


2022-08-08T04:08:18.688Z END RequestId: 6ec642a2-84d6-4e09-8155-ad8c0cbefd52

2022-08-08T04:08:18.688Z REPORT RequestId: 6ec642a2-84d6-4e09-8155-ad8c0cbefd52 Duration: 878.21 ms Billed Duration: 879 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 114 MB
```

It is quite confusing and difficult to follow the each request log.

I am thinking to right the script to parse the log and set the each RequestID.

However, I am afraid it is the invention of wheel.

Is there any practical behaivor to parse the lambda logs?

Answer (score 1):

[CloudWatch Log Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AnalyzingLogData.html) console can be used to filter the requests by ID. If you have your `requestId` you can select your lambda as a log group and write a short query (just be sure to set the correct time frame in the top right).

Something like this would work:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| sort @timestamp asc
| filter @requestId = "6ec642a2-84d6-4e09-8155-ad8c0cbefd52"
```